# Permanently exclude directory in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13

I have an IntelliJ project that includes a directory of some huge files.  Since those files were added to the project, we've noticed a degradation in performance such as momentary freezes and general sluggishness.  Marking the directory as excluded (context menu -> Mark Directory As -> Excluded) seems to help the problem.  However, this option is never persisted across sessions, so that when I reopen IntelliJ and open the project the folder is not marked as excluded.  How can I permanently mark this directory as excluded?

Running IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4 on Mac OS X 10.9.4.

Comment: The fact that excluded is not persisted across session seems to be a bug to me. I would open a bug report with them: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: Thanks @Michael.  I've filed a bug here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127907

Answer (score 3):

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.4 and Bazel build and was trying to exclude `.bazel-cache` directory so that it does not pop-up in search. Unfortunately, neither `osundblad`'s nor `cobbzilla`'s answer resulted in permanently hiding that directory.

What helped instead:

```
File -> Settings -> Editor -> File Types -> Ignore files and folders
```

and added `.bazel-cache` separated with `;`.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on osundblad's answer, this now works fine in more recent versions of IntelliJ:

- Open the module settings for the source module that is rooted somewhere above the directories you want to exclude. If you right-click on the directory in the Project view, you should see `Open Module Settings` in the context menu, click that.
- The "Project Structure" window should appear, with tabs named `Sources`, `Paths`, and `Dependencies`
- In the `Sources` tab, at the bottom of the file-tree control, find the text box labeled `Exclude Files`
- Say you had directories `foo` and `bar/baz` that you wanted to exclude: enter `foo*;bar/baz*;` apply/OK the changes, and they will be permanently excluded from the project.

Answer (score -1):

In project Settings under Sources tab you can mark directories as excluded.